# sharepoint foundation workflow not starting automatically

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I am working with Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and I am creating a workflow which must start automatically when an item from the listX is changed.

However, this workflow not starting automatically. =(

In setting up the workflow list appears but no flow in progress. 
Created within the workflow list and a reusable, but neither start.

In the options beginning of the workflow (in SPD), I left only enabled the automatic start when an item is changed.

Can anyone tell me why this?

Comment: If you are farm admin the workflow wont trigger.

Comment: Yes, I'm the administrator. However, the client has just released this access to development

Comment: Try to edit a list item with another account and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Workflows doesn't start workflow automatically if the list item is created by system account. If you use account of application pool to create items the workflow will not be started automatically. Use another account to start workflows.